# Difference between a hydrogen ion and a proton

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, hydrogen, binding-energy, ionization-energy

I've run into a bit of a problem on this weeks coursework.

> A proton and an electron initially at rest combine to form hydrogen. Find the wavelength of the emitted photon?

So, as far as I can see, there are two ways to do this: Find the mass of an electron + a proton, find the mass of hydrogen, work out Δm and use E=mc^2 and work out wavelength from E

Secondly, I'd assume, since I thought ionised hydrogen is the same as a proton, just use E=13.6 eV then work out wavelength from that.

The problem is they give very different answers.

Now all my friends are telling me to go with the first, so I reckon that's probably the right one. But why? Is a proton different to a H+ ion?

Comment: Your two approaches are exactly the same. 13.6 eV is the binding energy of hydrogen. What binding energy *means* is the difference between the mass of the bound state and the mass of the constituent parts.

Comment: In terms of why these 2 approaches are giving you different answers, you are looking at a difference in energy $\sim 10eV$. the mass of a proton $\sim 10^9 eV$. In order to get back that energy difference of $13.6eV$ to 3sf you will need the mass of the proton and the hydrogen atom to 10sf, and a similar level of precision with any unit conversion factors. I'm betting that is where your error occurred. Going back to $E=Mc^2$ is not the best approach to this calculation.

Comment: Sorry, I should add here that the answer is two orders of magnitude out - 2800 eV compared to 13.6. I used 9 sig figs:
(9.10938291*10^-31)+(1.67262178*10^-27)-1.67352766*10^-27 = 5.05*10^-33 = Δm
(5.05*10^-33)*(3*10^8)^2 = 4.55*10^-16 joules, or 2800 MeV

Answer (score 2):

The answers in the comments are both correct - a couple of points to add.

First think about the reverse process - how would you work out the energy required to break up the proton and electron in hydrogen to form a proton and electron. This is the same as the energy that needs to be released on formation of a hydrogen atom. I think you have figured this out from your question, but the point in the comment about it being easier to work things out this way is very good - the change in mass between H and a proton plus and electron is very small and this is not such a good way to work things out.

Secondly, the question is not particularly well put. In reality the hydrogen atom could be formed with the electron in any level; n=1, 2, 3 etc. and the wavelength of the photon would be different in each case. The answers described in the comments and the methods you suggest both assume that you are forming a hydrogen atom in the ground state.

Finally $H^+$ is equivalent to a proton - unless you are thinking of a hydrogen nucleus of mass 2 with one proton and one neutron, but we normally write that as $D^+$.

Comment: From what is said in these comments, may I infer that an excited hydrogen atom is HEAVIER than a ground-state atom?

Comment: @Sofia - yes this is true! It would be nice to be able to build a mass spectrometer that could tell the difference between say $He^+$ and $He^{+*}$ - ground state Helium ion and excited Helium ion, but I don't think we have enough mass resolution for that at the moment. More about this topic in answer to question at http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145972/is-it-theretically-possible-to-reduce-inertial-mass-without-reducing-matter-qu/145985#145985